# Maximum number of keys in Yedis (Yugabyte Redis)?

Tags: redis, yugabytedb

[Redis FAQ](https://redis.io/topics/faq) says maximum number of keys in a database is 2^32 - 1. However, that page has not been updated since 2010. In a Google groups thread, somebody said that the max number of keys is 2^32 - 1 on a 32 bit system, and 2^64 - 1 on a 64 bit system. I have been looking for any info on the maximum number of keys in a Yedis database. Can anyone please tell me what the number is? Also, is Yedis multithreaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. YugabyteDB YEDIS (or YCQL/YSQL for that matter) does NOT have a 2^32 (4B) limitation on number of keys. The theoretical limit is likely to be 2^64 - 1, because queries like select count(*) return a int64. For example, in the  experiment [described in this post](https://blog.yugabyte.com/performance-benchmarks-tb-database-cluster-high-data-density-nodes/), 20 billion keys were loaded.
2. Yes, YEDIS is multi-threaded, and can take advantage of multi-core machines